# Using limit () and offset () in QueryBuilder (ANDROID , ORMLITE)

Tags: android, list, limit, offset, ormlite

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public List<Picture> returnLimitedList(int offset, int end) {
    List<Picture> pictureList = new ArrayList<Picture>();
    int startRow = offset;
    int maxRows = end;
    try {
        QueryBuilder<Picture, Integer> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.offset(startRow).limit(maxRows);
        pictureList = dao.query(queryBuilder.prepare());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return pictureList;
}
```

- I have a table of Pictures in the database, and must return a limited list, 20 lines at a time.
- But when I use ex: QueryBuilder.offset(11).limit(30);
- I can not return the list limited to 20 lines.
- The list only comes to me with the limit.
- It's as if the offset remain always with value 0
- ex: (0 - 30)
- Is there any other way to return a limited list for initial index and end index?
- Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you turn on Android logging and post what queries are being applied?  http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging

Comment: May be because that limit(int maxRows) and offset(int startRow) are deprecated. you should use Long type So try :

public List<Picture> returnLimitedList(Long offset, Long end) {
....
and then :

QueryBuilder.offset(11L).limit(30L);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This question was asked two months ago, but I'll answer if anyone stumbled on the same problem as I did.

There's misunderstanding about what `offset` means in this case, here follows what SQLite Documentations says about it

> If an expression has an OFFSET clause, then the first M rows are omitted from the result set returned by the SELECT statement and the next N rows are returned, where M and N are the values that the OFFSET and LIMIT clauses evaluate to, respectively.

[Source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby)

Based on your query, you'll return 30 lines starting at the #11 line.

So the correct way is:

```
queryBuilder.offset(startRow).limit(20);
```

With `limit` being the number of rows that will return, not the ending row.

```
pictureList = dao.query(queryBuilder.prepare());
```

And the returned `List` with the first value starting on `pictureList.get(0)`

**Edit:** @Gray 's help on comments

Comment: +1.  You might want to also point out that limit is the number of rows, not the ending row.  Also, the rows that are returned are always 0 based.

Comment: @Rigotti, If i want my query to return 5 rows at a time. What should i use?